# shell script to login in another server using another name

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I want to write a shell script to ssh to another unix server with another username.
Unix server which I am using is SunOS.

I have tried many options such as expect tool and sshpass but none of them worked, can someone help me with the script using sshpass as I have heard that it provides a secure login.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ssh to another server and list only the directories inside a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652387/ssh-to-another-server-and-list-only-the-directories-inside-a-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are user `bob` on the localhost and want to `ssh` to `sunmachine` as `fred` you would do:

```
$ ssh fred@sunmachine
```

This would log you into `sunmachine` as `fred`, not `bob`.

You can also use the config file `~/.ssh/config` to set aliases:

```
Host sun 
Host sunmachine.domain.co.uk
User fred
```

Now you can just type *(as any user)*:

```
$ ssh sun 
# ssh fred@sunmachine.domain.co.uk <- the un-aliased command that is run
```

Note: Set up [key based authenitication](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/ssh-key-based-authentication-setup-from-openssh-to-ssh2/) so you are not prompted to enter your password.

Comment: I am requiring a shell script that automatically send the password and I can login to sunmachine.domain.co.uk with the username fred without intracting with the server.

Comment: You want to use [key based authenitication](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/ssh-key-based-authentication-setup-from-openssh-to-ssh2/) then!

Comment: I am not the superuser, I don't think I have the privelege to do so

Comment: let the username be fred for destination server and the password be fred123.

Comment: You don't need sudo privileges. Key based authentication is a much better approach then storing your password in plaintext in a script.

Comment: I want to login by script as script as ssh fred@sunmachine.domain.co.uk, then I want the script to automatically provide the password and let me log in

Comment: That is a massive security flaw, you are on your own.

Comment: how can I use sudo_O, do I have to give username and password along with it?