# ssh to another server and list only the directories inside a directory

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

dev1.ab.com is the current server, I have to ssh to tes1.ab.com, move inside the path /spfs/tomcat/dir and list all the directories (no files) present there.

For this I am using the below command from the command line of dev1.ab.co

**ssh tes1.ab.com " ls -1d */ /spfs/tomcat/dir "**

but in output I am getting output the directories of home is /spfs/tomcat, I have also tried

**ssh tes1.ab.com " ls -lrt /spfs/tomcat/dir | ls -1d */"**

**ssh tes1.ab.com " cd /spfs/tomcat/dir | ls -1d */"**

and ended up with nearly same result.

can someone help me to write a command in command line of dev1.ab.com to ssh to tes1.ab.com and get the output as the list of directories present in /spfs/tomcat/dir directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` instead of `ls`.

`ssh tes1.ab.com "find /my/folder -type d"`

add `-maxdepth 1` to list only the first level

Comment: Can you please write the complete command for me, actually I tried
ssh tes1.ab.com "find /spfs/tomcat/dir | ls -1d */"
But getting the same output.

Comment: That was the complete command. `ssh tes1.ab.com "find /my/folder -type d -maxdepth 1"`  putting a * after `ls` does would not work. You could filter by adding a `-name '*.txt'` parameter though.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following

ssh tes1.ab.com 'ls -ld /spfs/tomcat/dir/*/'

to list all the directories alone inside /spfs/tomcat/dir